# Android: Trouble declaring intent to be fired from a pendingIntent in a notification; done in a broadcastReceiver

Tags: android, multithreading, sms, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I would like to send a notification in a broadcast receiver. the notification should launch the default sms app.

Ultimately I want to create my own notifications for incoming text messages consistent with what the deault app, Handcent, and Chomp do.

I have the code to detect the threadId of the incoming sms.

How can I craft the intent to attach to the pendingIntent of the notification?

The following shows how to launch the sms app opening a particular thread, but the Intent creates a null pointer when I initialize it. Is it because it is being initialized in a broadcastReceiver, and not an activity?

[How to open up a specific SMS in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412221/how-to-open-up-a-specify-sms-in-android)

Comment: "Using a broadcastreceiver to detect and process an incoming text message is straight forward" -- except that it is not part of the Android SDK and so may not work in future versions of Android.

Comment: Wouldn't Chomp SMS, and Handcent use such a strategy?

Comment: Yes. As your mother may have once asked, if your friends all decide to jump off a cliff, would you jump off the cliff too?