# How to open specific conversation in default sms app in Android 6 (api 23)

Tags: android, sms

I am using the code from this answer:[How to open specific sms in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2809165/6414284) and it works perfectly.

But on Devices with **Android 6.0** (`apiVerion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M`) my App crashes.

**CrashLog:**

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] dat=content://mms-sms/conversations/50 flg=0x10000000 }
```

How can I make it work for this Android version?

Comment: I guess its because of permission. You should handle SMS permission at runtime in android 6.0 onwards. :) Please check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: @SripadRaj thank you- it's good gues, but it is not the problem. I am sure I have granted permission to READ_SMS.

To find out conversation **threadId** I search for specific text in received SMS's and after it was found I am opening it in default app. If I had permission problem, I would not be able find **threadId** in first place. And olso whole SMS related code is inside this condition:
 `if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(App.context, android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {`

Do you have any other guesses?

Comment: i guess it is unable to resolve the intent properly. Maybe try setting type to intent like this? `intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");`

Comment: No luck. It Still does not work. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround: I do not open SMS Conversation in default app by the id of SMS thread, but by the **phone number**. And it works this way in Android 6.

```
Intent androidSix = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", "phone_number_in_string", null));
startActivity(androidSix);
```